# Why my code igniter controller works partially?

Tags: codeigniter

I have enabled the query string settings and works fine for all the query string related URL's but except for this login controller... when I try like this, it gives me an error,

404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

URL : www.test.com/login/?sType=1

but when I access without query string, www.test.com/login/ ... works fine...

similarly other query string urls working fine as below, 
http://www.test.com/core/child/register/?sIds=3,4,&type=1
etc.,

How can I fix this issue?

My login controller,

```
function Login()    
{   
    parent::Controller();
    $this->load->model("user_login_model");         
    $this->load->library('user_agent');
}

// to load the login screen
function index() 
{       
    //$this->load->model("user_login_model");           
    $this->load->view('login/user_login_form');         
}


// to show as login
function show() 
{
    $this->load->view('login/user_login_form');     
}

// to process the login 
function checkuser() 
{       


}

// to logout
function logout() 
{   

}
```

}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/controllers/welcome.php */

Comment: Please paste the contents of your controller

Comment: What version of PHP/ CI are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced some problems in the past when there is only one element in query string. Try this:

www.test.com/login/?sType=1&n=1

It might work.

Comment: still , the same error displays.. but when I try like this, it works, how come?? http://test.com/login/index/?sType=1

Comment: Ok so I think CodeIgniter has difficulty finding the controller function to land to. If we provide the controller function explicitly (index) in your case, then it works

Comment: actually, index works fine in my local but when i deploy online, it fails .. only it works if i call login/index/?sType=1 ...?